# How to launch terminal on login

Tags: autostart, startup-applications

How could I get the terminal to be launched once I have logged in, so that typing commands is much simpler?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Press the *Super* key (windows key).
2. Type *"Startup Applications"*
3. Click on the `Startup Applications` option
4. Click *"Add"*
5. In  the *"name"* field, type `Terminal`
6. In the *"command"* field, type `gnome-terminal`
7. Click *"Add"*

You are done! Next time you login, the terminal app will be launched.

Comment: It would be better to use `x-terminal-emulator` instead of `gnome-terminal`, so if the user uses `update-alternatives` to switch to a different default terminal emulator it gets used instead. Mind if I edit this in?

Comment: In ubuntu 20_04 it is `qterminal`, the desktop is `lxqt`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this without GUI:

1. On your terminal, navigate to `.config/autostart` directory. `.config/autostart` may be in your home directory:

   ```
   cd ~/.config/autostart
   ```
2. Open the (new) `gnome-terminal.desktop` file with your favourite text editor. I use `vi`:

   ```
   vi gnome-terminal.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following code in the file. Update some lines if you like as you find suitable, or simply use as is:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=gnome-terminal
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=false
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
   Name[en_NG]=Terminal
   Name=Terminal
   Comment[en_NG]=Start Terminal On Startup
   Comment=Start Terminal On Startup
   ```
4. Save the file, and you're done.

If you need the terminal to both start and run a custom shell script command, edit the `gnome-terminal.desktop` file and change the line that goes `Exec=gnome-terminal` to `Exec=gnome-terminal --command "path/to/your/shell/script"`.

Comment: This approach is more clear and more flexible. Like easily bash commands can also be executed`

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to have a terminal window open on **every** login there is a simple way to get one as soon as you need it: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> will open a terminal window immediately.

Comment: Not really the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Works for me on Lubuntu

Comment: Well it's a way to open the terminal, but OP is looking to get it started automatically at the startup.

Comment: I cannot vote for this (since it does not address the OP's question), but I still found this really useful: still works in Debian KDE