# Automatic start-up for Terminal

Tags: command-line

For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version , I search up something about starting terminal window, but Ii think these are not updated, 
When I search,

[How to launch terminal on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308581/how-to-launch-terminal-on-login)

I go the way to open terminal automatically by GUI but from the line command not up-to-date,
Could you help how to do complete this task over terminal,

Thanks, solfish

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/914392/367990 ? That answer should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Or check out this question https://askubuntu.com/q/598195/367990